# React and useReducer unable to access the state value

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

relatively new to React so please excuse me for this question.

Below is a VERY basic form with a submission button and ability to listen for value changes on a users username and password.

The problem that I am facing is that as soon as I type anything into the form, it throws this error:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

(image isn't uploading: TypeError: Cannot read property "requestInFlight" of undefined)

Apparently `state` is nowhere to be found. I feel that I have done this verbatim from tutorials and the [documentations][2] so not sure what is throwing me off here.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import DispatchContext from "../DispatchContext";

// Boostrap Components
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

// Third party Components
import Axios from "axios";

const ACTIONS = {
  UPDATE_USERNAME: "update-username",
  UPDATE_PASSWORD: "update-password",
  REQUEST: "request",
};

const initialState = {
  username: "",
  password: "",
  requestInFlight: false,
};

function reducer(draft, { type, value }) {
  switch (type) {
    case ACTIONS.UPDATE_USERNAME:
      draft.username = value;
      return;
    case ACTIONS.UPDATE_PASSWORD:
      draft.password = value;
      return;
    case ACTIONS.REQUEST:
      draft.requestInFlight = value;
      return;
    default:
      return;
  }
}

function FormComponent({ type }) {
  const appDispatch = useContext(DispatchContext);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!state.requestInFlight) return;
    dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.REQUEST, value: true });
    const ourRequest = Axios.CancelToken.source();
    async function sendRequest() {
      try {
        const response = await Axios.post(`/api/${type}`, {
          username: state.username,
          password: state.password,
        });
        console.log(response);
        dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.REQUEST, value: false });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.REQUEST, value: false });
      }
    }
    sendRequest();
    return () => ourRequest.cancel();
  }, [state.requestInFlight]);

  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.REQUEST, value: true });
      }}
    >
      <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
        <Form.Label className="text-muted">Username</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Username"
          onChange={(e) =>
            dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.UPDATE_USERNAME, value: e.target.value })
          }
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
        <Form.Label className="text-muted">Password</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          onChange={(e) =>
            dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.UPDATE_PASSWORD, value: e.target.value })
          }
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
        {type}
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
}

export default FormComponent;


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD0sO.png
  [2]: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reducer setup is wrong, its returning undefined once it runs initially. You need to return your updated object instead of undefined.

```
function reducer(draft, { type, value }) {
  switch (type) {
    case ACTIONS.UPDATE_USERNAME:
      return {...draft, username: value };
    case ACTIONS.UPDATE_PASSWORD:
      return {...draft, password: value };
    case ACTIONS.REQUEST:
      return {...draft, requestInFlight: value };
    default:
      return draft;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is the correct answer but there is something I need to point out from your implementation.

Reducer functions have to be pure!
why? I recommend reading this article: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-redux-needs-reducers-to-be-pure-functions-d438c58ae468/

Comment: I have placed it outside of the main function. Does not that make it pure?

Comment: Here is a simple definition of a pure function that I found on Google. Pure functions are functions that accept an input and returns a value without modifying any data outside its scope(Side Effects). You are modifying `draft` in your function which makes it not pure